# Can I implement the Dining Philosophers Model to Web Workers?

Tags: javascript, java, c#, jquery, html

I have an idea. I want to code that problem. But I need multithreading as c#, java etc. I know there is no multithreading in javascript. But I heard "Web Workers". I am wondering the posibility. And I want to take visualization of people activity on the dining table. Do you think that is hard or possible?

Comment: It seems possible with Web Workers yes

Comment: What do you mean by implement the dining philosopher's model? It is a problem designed to show the challenges of avoiding deadlock. You can't code the problem, you can only code a solution to the problem. Any programming language that includes concurrency features can be used.

Comment: I know that is a problem. But Stack overflow doesn't accept the problem which contains "problem" so wrote " model"